# Route Analysis, Save Route Results with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, route, analysis

I calculated routes with an arcpy script tool and now want to export or save it.
If I try it with

*result_route.export(arcpy.nax.RouteOutputDataType.Routes, my_path)*

there is always an error.

> 'Result' object has no attribute 'export'

This is my code so far:

```
route_layer = arcpy.na.MakeRouteAnalysisLayer(network, "Route Analysis", '', "FIND_BEST_ORDER", None, "LOCAL_TIME_AT_LOCATIONS", "ALONG_NETWORK", None, "DIRECTIONS", "LOCAL_TIME_AT_LOCATIONS")
arcpy.na.AddLocations(route_layer, "Stops", int_points_id, "Name # #;RouteName poly_Id #;Sequence # #;TimeWindowStart # #;TimeWindowEnd # #;LocationType # 0;CurbApproach # 0;Attr_Length # 0", "5000 Meters", None, "routes_ooe SHAPE;network_ooe_ND_Junctions NONE", "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "APPEND", "NO_SNAP", "5 Meters", "EXCLUDE", None)

result_route = arcpy.na.Solve("Route Analysis", "SKIP", "TERMINATE", None, '')

output_route_path = ws + "\\result_route_ooe"

result_route.export(arcpy.nax.RouteOutputDataType.Routes, output_route_path)
```

Comment: I think you are mixing arcpy.na with arcpy.nax. They are different libraries using different approaches. Here is an example using .na https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/network-analyst/make-route-analysis-layer.htm . Here is an example using .nax https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/network-analyst/route.htm

Comment: Thank you very much. That was it. I just had to request the SubLayer and afterwards I can just save it with CopyFeatures!
Thanks a lot!